# org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect support PostgreSQL 12.5

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate

should org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect support PostgreSQL 12.5 ?
Because normally I use

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect

But for a µService with geopoint requirement, we used this specific language (before we are in postgresql 9.5)

thank you very much
And best regards

Comment: PostgisDialect extends from Postgres82Dialect, which is PostgreSQL 8.2, which is older..

Comment: ok but can be work with PG 12 ? Is the good question

Comment: Newer tested this before, but I doubt that you will be able to use new Postgres API and features using that old dialect, the difference between 8 and 12..

Comment: @MarkiianBenovskyi isn't the question about features, my question is only if this dialect work on PG 12 properly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dialects also work for newer versions, but might not use all the new fancy features that newer PostgreSQL servers support.

Comment: Thank Christian Beikov, I only need to work properly with the oldest features not new features